# Specific Width Columns and Center-Aligned in a Table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, arrays, columns, lengths

I want to create a table with specific column width and also I want the cells to be center-aligned. How can I do that?

I tried the tabular environment, but i didn't get the wanted result. I think it can be done with the array environment, but I don't know how to use it.

Here is what I have done:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|m{3em}|m{3em}||m{9em}|}
        \hline
        \textlatin{A} & \textlatin{B} & \textlatin{Out} \\ \hline
        0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
        0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
        1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
        1 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: I guess you'r interested in horizontally centered contents. If that's correct, try to replace `m` with `wc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `array` package offers the `w` column type. By adding `l`, `r`or `c` you can determine the horizontal alignment of the contents in these columns. The column type also accepts a width argument, however, please keep in mind, that contents that exceed this width will not be split up into multiple lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|wc{3em}|wc{3em}||wc{9em}|}
        \hline
        A & B & Out \\ \hline
        0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
        0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
        1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
        1 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would design your table as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{w{c}{1em} w{c}{1em} !{\vline width 1pt} w{c}{2em}}
A   & B & Out   \\ 
        \hline
0   & 0 & 1     \\  
0   & 1 & 0     \\  
1   & 0 & 0     \\ 
1   & 1 & 0     \\ 
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a "dumb" anwser I found

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|ccc|ccc||ccccccc|}
    \hline
     & A &  &  & B &  &  & & & Out & & &  \\ \hline
     & 0 &  &  & 0 &  &  & & & 1   & & &  \\ \hline
     & 0 &  &  & 1 &  &  & & & 0   & & &  \\ \hline
     & 1 &  &  & 0 &  &  & & & 0   & & &  \\ \hline
     & 1 &  &  & 1 &  &  & & & 0   & & &  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption*{Πίνακας αληθείας \textlatin{NOR} πύλης δύο εισόδων}
\end{table}
```

Here I am creating colums with nothing, just to be there.